# formula over two columns in IEEE style

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, two-column, ieeetran

I have two questions:

1. why are the big braces `\left(` only rendered as small regular ones for most of the equations? How can these be rendered as bigger?
2. Using an IEEE two-column layout and some long formulae  I want to typeset the long ones over both columns. How can I acheive this?

---

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    % The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
    %\usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,lipsum}
    \usepackage{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \newacronym{rog}{ROG}{radius of gyration}

    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % formula here

    \begin{equation}
    \text{mean} ={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}
    \label{eq:mean}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    \text{weightedMean} = \frac{\sum_{i_1}^{n} w_i * x_i}{\sum_{i_1}^{n} w_i}
    \label{eq:weightedMean}
    \end{equation}

    Where $x_{long}$ and $y_{lat}$.

    \begin{equation}
    \text{centroid} = \left[ mean(x_{long}), mean(y_{lat}) \right]
    \label{eq:centroid}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    \text{distanceHaversine} = 2r \arcsin{\sqrt{
    \sin^2{\left(\frac{y_{lat_1}-y_{lat_2}}{2} \right)}
    + \cos(y_{lat_1}) \cos{y_{lat_2}} \sin^2{\left(\frac{x_{long_1}-x_{long_2}}{2} \right)}
    }}
    \label{eq:haversine}
    \end{equation}


    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text
    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text
    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text
    \end{document}
```

Currently is generated - but has the two issues
[image]

Comment: About the questions: 1) use `\big[` or `\bigg[` or a similar thing; 2) it's not easy (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255086/how-to-put-a-long-equation-spanning-two-columns-while-using-ieeetran) and you should check if the journal will accept the extra packages.

Comment: This post might be interesting for point 2: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255115/109339

Comment: Strangely big is not working. But the main problem is 2.

Comment: Indeed, I have read the two already, but so far have not managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

For the first point, you can use one of the pairs `\bigl... \bigr`,  `\Bigl... \Bbigr`, which often produce a better result than `\left ... \right`

As to your second question, I propose to use the  `strip` environment  from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle). Of course, as it is not a float, it is up to you to determine where to insert it in the code so that the resulting text remains consistent.

Unrelated: needless to load `amsfonts` when you load `amssymb`. Also `mean` should be declared as math operator, so that it be typeset in upshape, with a correct letterspacing, and a proper spacing w.r.t. possible indices or exponents. Last  indices which are actually text or text abbreviations should be typed as such.

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    % The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
    %\usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\mean}{mean}
    \usepackage{cuted} 
    \usepackage{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \newacronym{isp}{ISP}{internet service provider}
    \newacronym{poi}{POI}{point of interest}
    \newacronym{od}{OD}{origin destination}
    \newacronym{rog}{ROG}{radius of gyration}

    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % formula here

    \begin{equation}
    \mean ={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}
    \label{eq:mean}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    \text{weightedMean} = \frac{\sum_{i_1}^{n} w_i * x_i}{\sum_{i_1}^{n} w_i}
    \label{eq:weightedMean}
    \end{equation}

    Where $x_\text{long}$ and $y_\text{lat}$.

    \begin{equation}
    \text{centroid} = \bigl[ \mean(x_\text{long}),\mean(y_\text{lat}) \bigr]
    \label{eq:centroid}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{strip}
    \begin{equation}
    \text{distanceHaversine} = 2r \arcsin{\sqrt{
    \sin^2{\left(\frac{y_{lat_1}-y_{lat_2}}{2} \right)}
    + \cos(y_{\text{lat}_1}) \cos{y_{\text{lat}_2}} \sin^2{\left(\frac{x_{\text{long}_1}-x_{\text{long}_2}}{2} \right)}
    }}
    \label{eq:haversine}
    \end{equation}
    \end{strip}

    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text
    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text
    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it rendering `mean` for you but I only get `= ...`

Comment: @GeorgHeiler - Did you copy over Bernard's definition, *viz.*, `\DeclareMathOperator{\mean}{mean}`?

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I missed that one.

Answer (score 3):

You asked,

> 1. why are the big braces `\left(` only rendered as small regular ones for most of the equations? How can these be rendered as bigger?

The belief that `\left(` and `\right)` always create "large" parentheses, *irrespective of the material they enclose*, is widely held but, alas, wrong. As you've (re-)discovered, if the material enclosed by `\left( ... \right)` is not tall, then the surrounding "fence symbols" aren't either.

See the posting [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) for in-depth discussions of why `\left( ... \right)` is not a panacea. In fact, it can be quite wrong at times to use `\left( ... \right)`.

---

You also asked,

> 2. Using an IEEE two-column layout and some long formulae I want to typeset the long ones over both columns. How can I achieve this?

There *are* methods to display selected material, including displayed equations, across both columns. For the equation at hand, though, I can't see a good reason for not typesetting it across two lines. This may be achieved by switching from `\sqrt{...}` notation to `[...]^{1/2}` notation, switching from an `equation` environment to a `multline` environment, and indicating a line break right before the `+` symbol. Three possible solutions are shown in the following screenshot:

- use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` throughout;
- use `\mleft` and `\mright` to size the round parentheses -- the square brackets are sized via `\biggl` and `\biggr` as they span a line break;
- use `\left` and `\right` to size the round parentheses. Note what many would perceive an excessive amount of whitespace between `\sin^2` and `(`.

Speaking for myself, I'd say that the first solution is the best one.

---

[image]

Note that I've omitted several pairs of curly braces in the equations, e.g., in `\cos{y_{lat_2}}`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "multline" env.
\usepackage{mleftright} % for "\mleft" and "\mright" macros
% utility macro to typeset variable names:
\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or "\mathrm", or whatever

\begin{document}

\noindent 
With \verb+\Bigl+ and \verb+\Bigr+:
\begin{multline} \label{eq:haversine1}
\textnormal{distanceHaversine} = 2r \arcsin \Bigl[
   \sin^2 \Bigl(\frac{y_{\vn{lat}_1}-y_{\vn{lat}_2}}{2} \Bigr) \\
+ \cos y_{\vn{lat}_1} \cos y_{\vn{lat}_2} \sin^2
   \Bigl(\frac{x_{\vn{long}_1}-x_{\vn{long}_2}}{2} \Bigr) \Bigr]^{1/2}
\end{multline}

\bigskip\noindent
With \verb+\mleft+ and \verb+\mright+:
\begin{multline} \label{eq:haversine2}
\textnormal{distanceHaversine} = 2r \arcsin \biggl[
   \sin^2 \mleft(\frac{y_{\vn{lat}_1}-y_{\vn{lat}_2}}{2} \mright) \\
+ \cos y_{\vn{lat}_1} \cos y_{\vn{lat}_2} \sin^2
   \mleft(\frac{x_{\vn{long}_1}-x_{\vn{long}_2}}{2} \mright) \biggr]^{1/2}
\end{multline}

\bigskip\noindent
With \verb+\left+ and \verb+\right+:
\begin{multline} \label{eq:haversine3}
\textnormal{distanceHaversine} = 2r \arcsin \biggl[
   \sin^2 \left(\frac{y_{\vn{lat}_1}-y_{\vn{lat}_2}}{2} \right) \\
+ \cos y_{\vn{lat}_1} \cos y_{\vn{lat}_2} \sin^2
   \left(\frac{x_{\vn{long}_1}-x_{\vn{long}_2}}{2} \right) \biggr]^{1/2}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's question about allowing a line break in the vinculum of a square-root expression. I initially seemed to remember that this topic had come up before on TeX.SE, but then I couldn't find a prior posting. Anyway, it's not too difficult to introduce a line break by replacing

```
\sqrt{AAAA BBBB}
```

with

```
\sqrt{AAAA} \\ \overline{BBBB}
```

but the result -- see below -- looks *just awful*. (I inserted `\cdots` instructions to help indicate that the square root continued to the next line, but it didn't help much.) I suspect that readers will try to read the full expression as some kind weird fraction and get utterly and  hopelessly lost. In short, I wouldn't do it. Use `\Bigl[ ... \\ ... \Bigr]^{1/2}` notation instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
With \verb+\Bigl(+ , \verb+\Bigr)+ , and a line break in the vinculum:
\begin{multline} \label{eq:haversine4}
\textnormal{distanceHaversine} = 2r \arcsin \sqrt{\sin^2 
   \Bigl(\frac{y_{\vn{lat}_1}-y_{\vn{lat}_2}}{2} \Bigr) \cdots} \\[1ex]
\overline{\cdots+\cos y_{\vn{lat}_1} \cos y_{\vn{lat}_2} \sin^2
   \Bigl(\frac{x_{\vn{long}_1}-x_{\vn{long}_2}}{2} \Bigr) }
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really interesting. I have one more equation with a long `\sqrt` is it possible to break the sqrt as well?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler - Let me make sure I understand your follow-up question: Are you asking how to line-break the long horizontal bar that spans the argument of `\sqrt`?

Comment: Exactly. This is my question.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler - I seem to recall that there was once a query on just that topic, i.e., how to line-break the vinculum. Let me see if I can find that posting.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler - I wasn't able to locate a prior posting on TeX.SE on your question. I went ahead and posted an addendum to show how one might line-break the vinculum. Speaking for myself, I find the result *just awful" and hence wouldn't do it.