# How to get a matrix without overlapping in a two column page

Tags: matrices

I am writing a paper in JESTCH journal having document class \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}. I need to type a big matrix in a two column page. While I tried to type the whole matrix, I am facing the issue of overlapping of the matrix in two column page and the image is attached below.

[image]

I want to get my matrix without overlapping has same as the table format which fits in 1 column given below,

[image]

Can anyone help me to sort out this problem.
Here I am attaching the matrix latex code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\begin{document}

$$K=\left[\begin{matrix}
    1+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{6}} & x+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{6}}+{{x}^{7}} & 1+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{7}} & 1+x+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{5}}  \\
    1+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{7}} & x+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{6}}+{{x}^{7}} & {{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{7}} & {{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{6}}  \\
    x+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{6}}+{{x}^{7}} & 1+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{6}} & 1+x+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{6}}+{{x}^{7}} & {{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{7}}  \\
    {{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{6}} & 1+x+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{7}} & {{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{7}} & x+{{x}^{2}}+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{7}}\\
\end{matrix} \right]$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer maybe of use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255115/133968.

Comment: You might try with the `strip` environment, ftom the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: @Bernard, Sir, I tried `strip` environment. It works, but I felt some difficulty. When I used more than one `strip` environments frequently, I lost some sentences in between the `strip` environments. Could you please assist me to fix the problem. Thanking you in advance.