# How to adjust long (multiline equation) in two columns using IEEEtrans class

Tags: equations, ieeetran, amssymb

Following the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255086/how-to-put-a-long-equation-spanning-two-columns-while-using-ieeetran), I am trying to adjust long multiline equations. However, when I try to add more equations, the solution doesn't seems to be working in my case. I want an output something like that:

[image: Desired image]

(I have obtained it via `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}`. However, now I want to embed it in `IEEEtrans class`.

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage{cuted}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\usepackage{empheq}

\title{equation}

\begin{document}
\section{equations}
\begin{strip}
  \begin{align}
   \begin{gathered}
\textbf{R(Reg\_S)} = {} \forall X1 \in x1 \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; \\  X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1]  \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \wedge  X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \wedge X3[5]  
\coloneqq X1[6] \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\} 
   \end{gathered}
   \begin{gathered}
\textbf{R(Reg\_S)} = {} \forall X1 \in x1 \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; \\  X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1]  \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \wedge  X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \wedge X3[5]  
\coloneqq X1[6] \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\} 
   \end{gathered}
   \begin{gathered}
\textbf{R(Reg\_S)} = {} \forall X1 \in x1 \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; \\  X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1]  \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \wedge  X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \wedge X3[5]  
\coloneqq X1[6] \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\} 
   \end{gathered}
  \end{align}
\end{strip}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, see also  `\Aboxed` from mathtools.

Answer (score 1):

You can fit equations in a column with a mix of `align` and `split`. However, because 1 column really has little space, I had to do a trick with `\mathrlap` and `\hspace`. You can also make them span two columns and have more flexibility in formatting.

Below is code that demonstrate both cases. I chose `\wedge` as a point of split but you have to decide what's best for clarity.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}


\title{Equation}
\author{Name Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Equations}
\kant[1]:
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
    \mathrlap{\mathbf{R(Reg\_S)} = \forall X1 \in x1}
    & \\
    & \hspace{2em} \begin{aligned}[t]
                     & \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1] \\
                     & \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \\
                     & \wedge  X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \\
                     & \wedge X3[5] \coloneqq X1[6] \\
                     & \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \\
                     & \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\} 
                   \end{aligned}
  \end{split} \\
  \begin{split}
    \mathrlap{\mathbf{R(Reg\_S)} = \forall X1 \in x1}
    & \\
    & \hspace{2em} \begin{aligned}[t]
                     & \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1] \\
                     & \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \\
                     & \wedge X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \\
                     & \wedge X3[5] \coloneqq X1[6] \\
                     & \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\}
                   \end{aligned}
  \end{split} \\
  \begin{split}
    \mathrlap{\mathbf{R(Reg\_S)} = \forall X1 \in x1}
    & \\
    & \hspace{2em} \begin{aligned}[t]
                     & \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1] \\
                     & \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \\
                     & \wedge X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \\
                     & \wedge X3[5] \coloneqq X1[6] \\
                     & \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\} 
                   \end{aligned}
  \end{split}
\end{align}

\kant[2-5]
\begin{strip}
  \begin{align}
    \begin{split}
      \mathbf{R(Reg\_S)} = \forall X1 \in x1
      & \begin{aligned}[t]
          & \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1] \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \wedge  X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \wedge X3[5] \coloneqq X1[6] \\
          & \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\} 
        \end{aligned}
    \end{split} \\
    \begin{split}
      \mathbf{R(Reg\_S)} = \forall X1 \in x1
      & \begin{aligned}[t]
          & \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1] \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \wedge X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \wedge X3[5] \coloneqq X1[6] \\
          & \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{split} \\
    \begin{split}
      \mathbf{R(Reg\_S)} = \forall X1 \in x1
      & \begin{aligned}[t]
          & \wedge \forall X3 \in x3 \; | \; X3[1] \coloneqq X1[1] \wedge X3[3] \coloneqq X1[3] \wedge X3[4] \coloneqq X1[4] \wedge X3[5] \coloneqq X1[6] \\
          & \wedge {x3}' \coloneqq x3 \cup \{X3[1], X3[3], X3[4], X3[5]\} 
        \end{aligned}
    \end{split}
  \end{align}
\end{strip}

\kant[6-8]
\end{document}
```

The screenshot

[image]

Since `split` breaks column continuation, such that text continues in the next column before the `split`, I'd personally prefer to put an equation in one column or either at the top or bottom of a page--for the latter case, a package [stfloats](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stfloats) might be of help.